# What are the extended trading market hours during a partial trading day for US stocks

Tags: nasdaq, after-hours-trading, nyse

Day after thanksgiving and Christmas Eve are example for partial trading days for NYSE and NASDAQ exchanges. During these days, normal trading takes place from 9:30 AM EST to 1 PM EST. I searched but nowhere found what are the pre and post market hours for these partial trading day?
I know during a normal trading day these hours are from 4AM to 9:30AM & 4PM to 8PM EST respectively.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I was able to find the answer. There is no change in the duration of pre and post market hours on a partial trading day.
Pre market starts from 4 AM ends at 9:30 AM.
Normal market starts at 9:30 and ends at 1 PM (because of partial trading day)
Post market starts at 1 PM and ends at 5 PM.